# How can I check if a commit exists in a pull request on GitHub?

Tags: github, git-commit, pull-request, github-cli

So I have a list of commits SHAs to check. In a given commit SHA let's say 123ab45, I want to see if the commit is linked to a PR in the branch.

Is there any command that I can put to check that?

Comment: Consider looking at the github cli?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yup I did. I have used Github Cli before to open a PR but I could not find anything that check PR with the given commit SHA key. I just wondered if anyone has done before.

Comment: Use the [tag:github-cli] tag, not the [tag:git] tag, for questions about the `gh` command. (I fixed the tags)

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the GitHub CLI version 2.7 or above:

```
gh search prs 123ab45
```

This is also supported by the [search](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commit-sha) functionality on `github.com`.

Enter at least the first seven characters of the commit SHA into the Pull Request search bar, or navigate directly to this URL:

```
https://github.com/your-repo/pulls?q=is%3Apr+123ab45+
```

Answer (score 2):

`git` has no concept of "pull request". This is a feature that is added by services built on top of `git` such as Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab, etc. There is no `git` command to do what you ask. To do this you will need to use their tools and APIs. The exact solution here depends on which of these services you use.

Comment: I know there is something called github cli. I once opened a PR on github with something like `gh pr create`. But I could not seem to figure out for this case with the given SHA

Comment: @appix I should have asked which cloud service you use. Assuming you are using github, there is probably a way to do what you want with the github cli. I've never used it so can't provide any more suggestions than google its docs.