# Github action on push if-and-only-if not an active PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repo with a **GitHub Action** `CI Workflow` that runs jobs `pytest` and `job2` **on pull requests**,  and both jobs must pass.

I also want **another workflow** to run that **same pytest on every push** (call this `pytest_on_push`), so users are warned if commits break a branch before they make a PR.

However, I **do not want** `pytest_on_push` **to run on pushes to a branch AFTER the branch has an open PR**, because it unnecessarily duplicates the pytest job.

How can this be done?

I've tried without success:

- preventing jobs or steps in pytest_on_push via `if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'`
- Looking for some syntax to define `on: push if not pull_request`

Example files:

```
name: CI Workflow
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened ]

jobs:
  pytest:
    name: pytest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run Pytest
        run: make test-ci

      - name: Archive unit test reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: coverage.xml
          path: ./coverage.xml

  job2:
    name: job2 for POR
    needs: pytest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      {do stuff}
```

```
name: pytest_on_push
on:
  # Apply pytest on push to any branch expect dev & prod
  # (these should be tested by ci.yml operating on any PR to those branches)
  # Can condition be defined to ignore if pull_request? 
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - develop
      - production

jobs:
  pytest:
    name: pytest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Can an if statement here prevent job steps running?

    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run Pytest
        run: make test-ci
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72222069/10871900 might help you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to make use of the linked issue?  github CLI & search bar on github don't directly map to GitHub actions executed via yaml.  Are you suggesting that I can use an `if` statement with some check along the lines of fetch all open PRs then check if commit SHA is in any of those PRs?  Feels like there should be a much more direct check of is-this-commit-to-an-open-PR available from within the commit...  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes. If you don't find another way, you could always use the GitHub CLI (or similar) for checking that.